# why are conservative vector fields curl-free?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The book told me that, if a vector field $\vec{F} = Mi + Nj$ is conservative, then

$$
M_y = N_x
$$

But why is this true?

Answer (score 5):

The important idea is that if $f$ is of class $C^2$ (meaning it is at least twice differentiable, and those derivatives are continuous), then mixed partials are equal (which is called [Clairaut's theorem](http://people.sju.edu/~pklingsb/clairaut.pdf)), and therefore a quick calculation shows that [the curl of a gradient is zero](http://mathinsight.org/curl_gradient_zero).

For what it's worth, you should be aware that the requirement that $M_y=N_x$ is only a *necessary* and [not a sufficient condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields) for $F$ to be a conservative vector field. There are topological obstructions which prevent curl-free vector fields from being conservative, a fact which marks [the beginning of de Rham cohomology](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~statmath/stinc/database/notes/puncturedplane.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

$$M=f_x$$
$$N=f_y$$
$$M_y=\cdots$$
$$N_x=\cdots$$